# I can't get Three.js to render a scene from an imported OBJ file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, three.js, 3d, webgl

I'm not able to get my Three.js scene to display on HTML canvas. I'm importing an OBJ file which is importing correctly. It shows all details, such as Meshes, materials, etc. correctly. Here is my code:

```
export function TestScene() {
    const mountRef = useRef(null);
    const scene = new THREE.Scene();
    const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1,
                                               1000);
    const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    const loader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

    useEffect(() => {

        mountRef.current.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

        const animate = function () {
            requestAnimationFrame(animate);
            renderer.render(scene, camera);
        };

        loader.load(

            'object.obj',

            function (object) {
              scene.add(object);
              camera.position.z = 100;

            },
            function (xhr) {
              console.log((xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100) + '% loaded');

            },
            function (error) {

              console.log(error);
            }
        );

        animate()
    }, [])

    return <>
        <h1 id='test' style={{ color: 'black' }}>blahhh</h1>
        <div ref={mountRef} />
        </>
}
```

Comment: Do you have any lights in your scene? Maybe that's the problem.

Comment: I did a light with intensity. I did see its in the the scene now but still no render

Comment: Here is dev server showing the scene in console after loading http://40.114.68.103:3000/

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve my issue by configuring the Orbital controls which took me two the model. I then adjusted the scaling using *object.scale.set(.0001, .0001, .0001);* -

```
import { tsExportAssignment } from '@babel/types';
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useCallback } from 'react';
import { MTLLoader} from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/MTLLoader';
import { OBJLoader } from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/OBJLoader';
import { OrbitControls } from 'three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js'

const THREE = require('three')

export function TestScene() {
    const [update, setUpdate] = React.useState(0);
    const mountRef = useRef(null);
    const scene = new THREE.Scene();
    const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(100, window.innerWidth /
                                               window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
    const light = new THREE.HemisphereLight(0xffffbb, 0x080820, 1);
    const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true});
    renderer.setClearColor(0xffffff, 1);
    const loader = new OBJLoader();
    const mtlLoader = new MTLLoader()
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    const controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
    camera.position.set(0, 20, 20);
    controls.update();

    useEffect(() => {

        mountRef.current.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

        const animate = function () {
          requestAnimationFrame(animate);
          controls.update();
          renderer.render(scene, camera);
        };

        mtlLoader.load(
            'object.mtl',
            (materials) => {
                materials.preload()
                loader.setMaterials(materials)
                console.log(materials)

                loader.load(

                    'object.obj',

                    function (object) {
                        object.scale.set(.0001, .0001, .0001);
                        scene.add(object);
                        scene.add(camera);
                        scene.add(light);
                        console.log(scene)
                        animate()
                    },
                    function (xhr) {
                        const loading = (xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100)
                        if(loading === 100) {
                            setUpdate(loading)
                        }
                        console.log((xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100) + '% loaded');
                    },
                    function (error) {

                        console.log(error);
                    }
                );
            });
    }, [])

    console.log(scene)
    return <>
        <>{update !== 100 ? <h5 id='test' style={{ color: 'black' }}
        className="blinking">Loading OBJ..</h5> : <h5 style={{ color: 'black' }}>File
        Loaded, Rendering Scene</h5>}</>
        <div ref={mountRef} />
        </>
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by *"...took me two the model"*? Two of what? Do you mean *"took me two Orbital controls to model"* (two changes, three extra words, and one deletion)? Or something else? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70547414/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).